# help needed with sqlite manager

Tags: xcode, sqlite, sqlitemanager

hi i m using sqlite manager now the manager is showing me tables inside the database but when i m running my code it says that the table is not found. Here is my code. please can someone point out my mistake.

```
    - (IBAction)saveDatabase
{

    float x = [_openingBalance.text floatValue];
    NSNumber *amount = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x];

    float y = [_monthlyBudget.text floatValue];
    NSNumber *budget = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y];

    _uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "insert into Account (name, type , currencyCode  , parentAccount  , currentBalance , monthlyBudget , monthlyBudgetPercentage ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
            sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [_accountName.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, 1);

            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [@"PKR" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 4, 1);

            sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 5, [amount doubleValue]);

            sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 6, [budget doubleValue]);

            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 7, 0);
        }

        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
            NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %lld", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
        }
        char* errmsg;
        sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}
```

The error is `Error: no such table: Account`

Comment: delete your app from simulator, run Clean All in xcode and then run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your file path..

```
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];
```